# Cannot install wine32/win64 libc6:i386

Tags: apt, software-installation, kali-linux, wine

Hello I get this error when I try to install wine32 and wine64:

> Read package list ... Done Generating dependency tree ... Done Read
> status information ... Done some packages cannot be installed. This
> may mean that an impossible situation has been requested or, if you
> are using a development distribution, that some required packages have
> not yet been created or have been removed from Incoming. The following
> information can help resolve the situation: The following packages
> have unsatisfied dependencies: libvkd3d1: i386: It depends: libc6:
> i386 (> = 2.34) but version 2.333-6 is about to be installed E: Unable
> to fix problems, there are bad packages blocked.
>
> The following packages have unsatisfied dependencies: libvkd3d1: i386:
> It depends: libc6: i386 (> = 2.34) but version 2.333-6 is about to be
> installed E: Unable to fix problems, there are bad packages blocked.

I have tryed to do:

```
sudo apt install libc6:i386=2.33-6
```

And reinstall too instead of install, but nothing changed.
Does anybody has an idea to solve this?

Thank you!

```
└─ $ apt policy libc6: {amd64, i386}
libc6:
  Installed: 2.33-6
  Candidate: 2.33-6
  Version table:
 *** 2.33-6 500
        500 https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling / main amd64 Packages
        100 / var / lib / dpkg / status
libc6: i386:
  Installed: 2.33-6
  Candidate: 2.33-6
  Version table:
 *** 2.33-6 500
        500 https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling / main i386 Packages
        100 / var / lib / dpkg / status
```

Comment: Start with `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov already done

Comment: Can you repeat the command above but add `LANG=C ` before it, e.g. `LANG=C apt do something`? No one speaks Italian here. Then edit your question and show the English output, please

Comment: sudo LANG=C command dpkg --add-architecture i386

Like this?

Comment: Oh ok I did this: LANG=C command sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 but it doesn't display any error. I have updated my question ^^

Comment: Thanks, we've got @StephenKitt who's an expert in Debian, hopefully he'll chime in soon.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Ok thank you very much !

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the output of `apt policy libc6:{amd64,i386}`?

Comment: @Artem thanks for the ping attempt! (@ doesn’t work with a user who hasn’t participated in the post yet.)

Comment: I hope the feature is in the pipeline.

Comment: @StephenKitt Hello I' added the answer of the command (sorry I was on vacation)